# How to load an Interstitial ad in an activity and show it in the next one with AdMob?

Tags: java, android-activity, admob, interstitial

I'm trying to load an Intertstitial Ad in an activity and show it in a different one using Java and the AdMob SDK version 20.
Does anybody know how I can do that?

1st activity: StickerPackListActivity

```
public class StickerPackListActivity extends AddStickerPackActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LIST_DATA = "sticker_pack_list";
private static final int STICKER_PREVIEW_DISPLAY_LIMIT = 5;
private LinearLayoutManager packLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView packRecyclerView;
private StickerPackListAdapter allStickerPacksListAdapter;
private WhiteListCheckAsyncTask whiteListCheckAsyncTask;
private ArrayList<StickerPack> stickerPackList;
private AdView mBanner1;
private AdView mBanner2;
private AdView mBanner3;
private AdView mBanner4;
public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticker_pack_list);
    packRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sticker_pack_list);
    stickerPackList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LIST_DATA);
    showStickerPackList(stickerPackList);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.title_activity_sticker_packs_list, stickerPackList.size()));
    }

                        //Questa parte fa andare i banner, non eliminare.
    mBanner1 = findViewById(R.id.adViewtoplist);
    mBanner2 = findViewById(R.id.adViewbottomlist);
    mBanner3 = findViewById(R.id.adViewbottomlist2);
    mBanner4 = findViewById(R.id.adViewbottomlist3);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mBanner1.loadAd(adRequest);
    mBanner2.loadAd(adRequest);
    mBanner3.loadAd(adRequest);
    mBanner4.loadAd(adRequest);
                        //End
    InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                }
            });
}
```

Second Activity: StickerPackDetailsActivity

```
public class StickerPackDetailsActivity extends AddStickerPackActivity {

/**
 * Do not change below values of below 3 lines as this is also used by WhatsApp
 */
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID = "sticker_pack_id";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_AUTHORITY = "sticker_pack_authority";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_NAME = "sticker_pack_name";

public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_WEBSITE = "sticker_pack_website";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_EMAIL = "sticker_pack_email";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_PRIVACY_POLICY = "sticker_pack_privacy_policy";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LICENSE_AGREEMENT = "sticker_pack_license_agreement";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON = "sticker_pack_tray_icon";
public static final String EXTRA_SHOW_UP_BUTTON = "show_up_button";
public static final String EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_DATA = "sticker_pack";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
private StickerPreviewAdapter stickerPreviewAdapter;
private int numColumns;
private View addButton;
private View alreadyAddedText;
private StickerPack stickerPack;
private View divider;
private WhiteListCheckAsyncTask whiteListCheckAsyncTask;
public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sticker_pack_details);

    boolean showUpButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_UP_BUTTON, false);
    stickerPack = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_DATA);
    TextView packNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pack_name);
    TextView packPublisherTextView = findViewById(R.id.author);
    ImageView packTrayIcon = findViewById(R.id.tray_image);
    TextView packSizeTextView = findViewById(R.id.pack_size);

    addButton = findViewById(R.id.add_to_whatsapp_button);
    alreadyAddedText = findViewById(R.id.already_added_text);
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.sticker_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(pageLayoutListener);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(dividerScrollListener);
    divider = findViewById(R.id.divider);
    if (stickerPreviewAdapter == null) {
        stickerPreviewAdapter = new StickerPreviewAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), R.drawable.sticker_error, getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sticker_pack_details_image_size), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sticker_pack_details_image_padding), stickerPack);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(stickerPreviewAdapter);

    }
    packNameTextView.setText(stickerPack.name);
    packPublisherTextView.setText(stickerPack.publisher);
    packTrayIcon.setImageURI(StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.trayImageFile));
    packSizeTextView.setText(Formatter.formatShortFileSize(this, stickerPack.getTotalSize()));
    addButton.setOnClickListener(v -> addStickerPackToWhatsApp(stickerPack.identifier, stickerPack.name));

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(showUpButton);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(showUpButton ? getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_sticker_pack_details_multiple_pack) : getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.title_activity_sticker_packs_list, 1));
    }
}

private void launchInfoActivity(String publisherWebsite, String publisherEmail, String privacyPolicyWebsite, String licenseAgreementWebsite, String trayIconUriString) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(StickerPackDetailsActivity.this, StickerPackInfoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_ID, stickerPack.identifier);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_WEBSITE, publisherWebsite);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_EMAIL, publisherEmail);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_PRIVACY_POLICY, privacyPolicyWebsite);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_LICENSE_AGREEMENT, licenseAgreementWebsite);
    intent.putExtra(StickerPackDetailsActivity.EXTRA_STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON, trayIconUriString);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Both activities are cut short as I'd like to both load and show the ad respectively with the OnCreate method of the first and the second activity.

Answer (score 1):

First Activity Load Ad

```
public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

Now Create Function

```
public void InterstitialAd_load(){
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

      InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
        // an ad is loaded.
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
      }

      @Override
      public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
        // Handle the error
        Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
        mInterstitialAd = null;
      }
    });
}
```

Create Static Method to show Ad

```
public static void showAd(){
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
  mInterstitialAd.show(MyActivity.this);
}
}
```

Second Activity import class

```
import com.your.packagename.firstactivity.showad;
```

Second Activity call method

```
ShowAd();
```

Comment: I tried to do that. However, when the second activity loads, the app crashes

Comment: kindly post your code here so i can give you a solution

Comment: Try "make a method to show ad with static keyword and call it on next activity"

Comment: You can find it in the updated question

Comment: Check the updated Answer

Comment: It's giving me some problems. For the first activity, when creating the method, it does not allow me to put the name of the first activity in `mInterstitialAd.show(MyActivity.this);`. It says that I cannot refernce it from a static context.
In the second activity, when importing the class, it says it cannot resolve the symbol `showad`. I also tried to change the capital letters but nothing.
And in the end, the method `ShowAd();` cannot be resolved.
I tried changing capitalization in the various names, but it didn't help.

Comment: try this 
Declare on Top
'Activity activity;'

replace myactivity.this to activity
'mInterstitialAd.show(activity);'

Comment: Still says that the argument `activity` is non-static so it cannot be referenced in a static context. All the other problems persist.

Comment: Please help @Manees  :((((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to click a button to open another activity then the ad show up
then it's quite easy you can use this line in your onclick of the button that open the other activity

```
    mInterstitialAd.show(YourCurrentActivity.this); // note that mInterstitialAd is the Ad id
```